# Faster way of generating a sequence of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, loops, optimization

Say I want to generate the following recursive sequence:

[image]

which is the same sequence as the following in closed form:

[image]

But the objective is to write a function to generate the sequence with its recursive definition. So, the following is my function:

```
def gen_seq(n):
    '''
    n is the number of terms to generate in the sequence
    '''
    lis = [1] # starting number of the sequence
    for i in range(1,n):
        lis.append(lis[-1] + 2*(i+1) - 1)
    return lis
```

We can look at the first 10 terms of the sequence:

```
gen_seq(10)
>>> [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

If we look at the time taken to generate the first 10 million numbers in the sequence:

```
import time
t = time.time()
foo = gen_seq(10000000)
print('Time taken: {}s'.format(time.time()-t))

>>> Time taken: 6.146637201309204s
```

It takes 6.1 seconds. For 100 million numbers, the time taken would be 1 minute. With more complicated sequences, the time taken will be more.

How do I optimize this function to make it much faster?

Comment: You may want to take a look at a compiler like numba: https://numba.pydata.org/

Comment: The generalization from 10 million to 100 million elements is not generally true, since it depends on at which lengths the underlying list is resized and thus new memory needs to be allocated and old elements need to be copied. If you know the size already beforehand it's better to first create the list (e.g. `[None] * n`) and then fill it later on (this also works for recursive problems). Or you can use a generator of course.

Comment: Do you really need all 100,000,000 numbers in memory at once?

Comment: @chepner Actually I was generating 10 million numbers of the sequence with 2 different starting numbers and then analyzing the difference between the 2 sequences. So, I did not give much thought to memory and all that. In any case, even if I don't store the individual sequences in memory, I would need to store the difference of the sequences in memory at least.

Comment: The first level optimization in processing large numeric arrays in Python calls `numpy`. It uses optimized C routine to speed up numeric processing. `np.arange(100000)` is close to 30 times faster that `list(range(100000))`. If it does not apply to your use case (not good at recursive questions...) you will have to try Cython (the underlying numpy compiler) or numba.

Comment: @SergeBallesta A list comprehension similarly loops in C so regarding just the loop there is no difference to numpy. The speed-up comes from the fact in Python every number in the resulting list is represented by an object and hence comes with some overhead while numpy uses its own data type (`np.int64`) and just stores the numbers. Compare `np.arange(100_000, dtype=object)` and the speed-up is gone.

Comment: @a_guest: If seeking for performances, I would avoid to store numbers as objects in numpy! But your comment is fair. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If the closed form is available you can use a list comprehension. This has the advantage that all the required memory can be allocated right at the beginning:

```
seq = [(i + 1)**2 for i in range(1, n+1)]
```

Repeatedly appending to a list causes internal resizing of the underlying memory and thus involves unnecessary memory allocations and copies.

Without a closed form you can still use a generator:

```
def gen_seq(n):
    a = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        a += 2*i - 1
        yield a
```

### Performance comparison

```
In [1]: def f1(n): 
   ...:     return [(i + 1)**2 for i in range(1, n+1)] 
   ...:                                                                                       

In [2]: def gen_seq(n): 
   ...:     a = 0 
   ...:     for i in range(1, n+1): 
   ...:         a += 2*i - 1 
   ...:         yield a 
   ...:                                                                                       

In [3]: def f2(n): 
   ...:     return list(gen_seq(n)) 
   ...:                                                                                       

In [4]: %timeit f1(100_000)                                                                   
29.7 ms ± 271 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit f2(100_000)                                                                   
16.1 ms ± 176 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The generator version is almost 2x faster than the list comprehension. This is because the recursive version benefits from the relatively simple operations that are involved. Multiplying an integer by `2` is simply a 1-lshift and adding or subtracting a number is an O(N) operation where N is the number of digits. Multiplying two integers however is O(N*log(N)) and hence takes more time to compute. The recursive version benefits from the already-computed part `a_{n-1}` which it can reuse at each step.

Comment: Well, I didn't want to use a complicated sequence for this example. That's why I had used the simplest recursive sequence I could think of. Now I modified the example of the sequence to a slightly more complicated one. This one can't be generated by a simple range. The goal is to be optimize the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically in this case, you can just use `list(range(1, n))` which is much faster

```
import time
t = time.time()
print(list(range(1, 1_000_000)))
print(time.time() - t)
```

Takes less than 0.5 seconds.

Comment: Well, I didn't want to use a complicated sequence for this example. That's why I had used the simplest recursive sequence I could think of. Now I modified the example of the sequence to a slightly more complicated one. This one can't be generated by a simple range. The goal is to be optimize the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a **MUCH** faster method I came up with:

```
 % echo; ( time ( nice mawk2 'BEGIN { 

         __=_="0123456789"
                           gsub(".","\n&",_)
                         gsub(".","\\&&",__)
        ____=(___=8)~___
       
        while(--___) {
            
            gsub("[\n][^\n]+",__,_) 
        }
        gsub("[\n][0]+","\n",_)
         sub("^[\n]+",    "",_) print _ }' \
  \
   )| pvE9) |xxh128sum| ggPy '[a-z]*' | gcat -n | lgp3 | ecp       

 
     out9:  847MiB 0:00:02 [ 331MiB/s] [ 331MiB/s] [ <=> ]
( nice mawk2 ; )  

     2.04s user 0.42s system 95% cpu 2.587 total

     1  8f5f1006371048b6bed5837e6862d274  stdin

 
% echo; ( time ( nice jot 99999999 \
  \
   )| pvE9) |xxh128sum| ggPy '[a-z]*' | gcat -n | lgp3 | ecp

 
     out9:  847MiB 0:00:17 [48.6MiB/s] [48.6MiB/s] [  <=>  ]
( nice jot 99999999; )  

   17.28s user 0.18s system 99% cpu 17.473 total

     1  8f5f1006371048b6bed5837e6862d274  stdin

  ……………
```

This is just a demo of sequentially printing every integer

from        1
to 10^8 - 1

Adjust it accordingly to the strange you need, and use `substr()` like functions to extract the maximum point you need. From there you can convert it into `list/array/set` however you want it.

Right now the delimiter is set to line-feed `\n` just to have the output be byte-to-byte identical to jot/seq. Change it to like "," or space etc if it suits your purposes better.

And here's how much slower it is to use python3 range() ::

```
% echo; (time (nice python3 -c '
   
   import sys

   print(list(range(1,10**8)))' ) | pvE9 ) \
   \
   | mawk NF=NF RS='[, \n]+' FS='[\]\[\47]+' OFS='' \
   \
    |xxh128sum |  ggXy3 | gcat -n | lgp3 | ecp


 out9:  943MiB 0:00:21 [43.2MiB/s] [43.2MiB/s] [ <=> ]
 ( nice python3 -c ; )  

  5.06s user 0.80s system 26% cpu 21.853 total

 1  8f5f1006371048b6bed5837e6862d274  stdin
```

I don't know if splitting this into some sort of list/iterator would be slower or not in python3, but hopefully it won't be too slow.

UPDATE : Adding just pure `python3` iterator benchmarking of `seq` suggested by someone else, as well as built-in `range()` :

```
echo; (time (nice  python3 -c 'import sys

print(list(range(1,10**8)))' 

 ) | pvE9 ) | xxh128sum |  ggXy3 | gcat -n | lgp3 | ecp

 out9:  943MiB 0:00:05 [ 159MiB/s] [ 159MiB/s] [ <=> ]
 ( nice python3 -c ; ) 

  5.04s user 0.76s system 97% cpu 5.922 total

 1  fe8ac3910b876473326c20a90959ac2c  stdin


% echo; (time (nice  python3 -c 'import sys

  def seq(n,i=1):
    while i < n+1:
        yield i
        i+=1

 print(list(seq(10**8-1)))' ) 

| pvE9 ) | xxh128sum |  ggXy3 | gcat -n | lgp3 | ecp

 out9:  943MiB 0:00:11 [84.2MiB/s] [84.2MiB/s] [ <=> ]
 ( nice python3 -c ; )  

 10.21s user 0.89s system 98% cpu 11.213 total

 1  fe8ac3910b876473326c20a90959ac2c  stdin
```

Even the pure iterator from `range()` is at least 2.2x slower.  Recursion is definitely not the way to go if speed is your concern.

UPDATE 2 : Benchmarking a test print of every integer from 1 to just 1 shy of 1-billion  :

only ***26.3 seconds*** needed

```
echo; ( time ( nice mawk2 'BEGIN { __=_="0123456789"; gsub(".","\n&",_)+gsub(".","\\&&",__); ____=(___=9)~___; while(--___) { gsub("[\n][^\n]+",__,_) }; gsub("[\n][0]+","\n",_)+sub("^[\n]+","",_); print _ }' )| pvE9) |xxh128sum| ggPy '[a-z]*' | gcat -n | lgp3 | ecp           

 
     out9: 9.21GiB 0:00:26 [ 360MiB/s] [ 360MiB/s] [                           <=>                 ]
( nice mawk2 ; )  

       20.29s user 4.73s system 95% cpu 26.303 total

     1  9bb91d060632f3e08c6c4916824e5a7d  stdin
```

Answer (score 0):

The append function of the list makes me believe that we can do it faster, let us try with generators:

```
def seq(n,i=1):
    while i < n+1:
        yield i
        i+=1

import time
t = time.time()
foo = list(seq(10000000))
print('Time taken: {}s'.format(time.time()-t))
```

It is for me more than one second faster. I think it can be improved more.

Comment: The ``range`` builtin already allows to create such sequences. There is no need to define a separate helper.